# Magento 2: Add custom column to filter option in order grid?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, order-grid, column

I have created custom column in **sales_order** table in Magento 2. At the time placing order values is saved in that column. Now I want to this column to be available for filter option.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the performance, the Order Admin Grid will load the values from `sales_order_grid`. So, we need to add more columns to this table.

app/code/Vendor/SalesOrder/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesOrder\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quote = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';
        $orderGridTable = 'sales_order_grid';

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($quote),
                'custom_field',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );
        //Order table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'custom_field',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );

        //Order Grid table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderGridTable),
                'custom_field',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Attribute'
                ]
            );


        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Declare this column to ui grid:

app/code/Vendor/SalesOrder/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="custom_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Field</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Populate the custom field in `sales_order_grid`. See more here: [`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Grid.php::refresh()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Grid.php#L87)

app/code/Vendor/SalesOrder/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid"
                 type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_field" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_field</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Remember to create the `registration.php` and `module.xml`.

Comment: I have followed your answer and added my custom field to filter in order grid but values are not showing there in the select box my my field,plz help

Comment: I followed all the steps and added an class to the custom field inside the Ui/../Listing/Column, but when I export the Order, values are not showing in the CSV, while values are present in the Order Grid.

Comment: hai @Koha plz answr this https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/289872/80389

Comment: you buddy saved my day thumbs up