# How to Add Date with Time in Orders Filter : Magento 2 Admin Section

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, filter, datetime

**In M2 Admin I want to filter my orders with date and time**, by default date only in purchase filter section. How to add date and time here. Purchase Date with time already show in the order grid!. How can i achieve my needs .?
[image]

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately, it not works. If you got the solution then please update it here. :)

Comment: @Sumit Definitely

Answer (score 1):

I've found the right solution.

Put this to your column definition:

```
'filter_time' => true,
```

Should work for magento 1.x and also 2.x

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please use below date time picker]
[Please check this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/pattern-library/getting-user-input/date_time_selector/date_time_selector.html)

Try to override sales_order_grid.xml and change default date picker with date time picker.

Comment: where i'm edit the file to change datetime picker

Answer (score 0):

Please add "dateRange" in column

```
<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you got a solution for this?.Yes, Please share here.

I am also looking for the same but unfortunatly I haven't found any solutions.

Reply will be appreciated

Comment: Sorry brother, i'm helpless .. but if you want date tim picker in ui component please follow   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/magento-2-how-to-add-the-datetime-ui-component

Comment: @Shafeel sha, Thanks for prompt response. So, did you left as is or did any alternatives?. I need date time picker in filters only. I hope the link you have shared is not useful for me